# unable to store getDownloadUrl in state

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-hooks, google-api, google-cloud-storage

```
const [values, setValues] = useState({ description: "", postImgUrl: "" });
  const [imgPreview, setImgPreview] = useState();

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setImgPreview(URL.createObjectURL(e.target.files[0]));
    setFile(e.target.files[0]);
  };

  const sectionStyle = {
    backgroundImage: `url(${imgPreview})`,
  };

  const uploadData = async () => {
    const postImage = ref(storage, `postImages/${user.uid}/${uuidv4()}`);
    uploadBytes(postImage, file).then((snapshot) => {
      getDownloadURL(snapshot.ref).then((url) => {
        console.log("url link", url)
        //setUrlImg(url);
        setValues((prev) => ({ ...prev, postImgUrl: url }));
        console.log(values);
      });
    });

    
  };
```

I am trying to store my image src data in a state but its showing blank, when we console url only its showing url link but blank when console values, I am using firestore storage to store image.

[image]

Comment: setValues with function will be called asynchronously, so its possible that `console.log(values)` is still blank at that moment, if you put this log next to first line, I think you should be able to see the values there

Answer (score 0):

Your code is doing:

```js
console.log("url link", url)
setValues((prev) => ({ ...prev, postImgUrl: url }));
console.log(values);
```

but the "set state function" of `useState()` is an asynchronous function.  It will put the call to `setValues(....)` onto the asynchronous queue to be executed LATER, then JS will continue to the next statement (`console.log(values)`) but the `values` will not have changed.  It will change AFTER the current rendering of your component is done.

In other words, your code is setting the value but the way you are testing the value is incorrect....you are testing the value before the setting happens.  You really want to get comfortable with the way that JavaScript (and React) work with regards to Asynchronous.

I strongly encourage people to watch the video ***JavaScript: Understanding the Weird Parts*** multiple times: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bv_5Zv5c-Ts&t=1s

Especially the parts about Synchronous and Asynchronous code execution (time links are in the video description).